# Nginx + Gunicorn problem with Let's Encrypt certificate

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, gunicorn, lets-encrypt

I have a problem with a Django application served by Nginx + Gunicorn: configured in HTTP it works correctly; after installing and requesting an SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt and changing the configuration, the request to the application times out.

This is the configurations I'm using:

**Socket**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**Systemd service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=user
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/application
ExecStart=/var/www/application/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          DjangoApp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Nginx configuration**:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/application/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I also tried to disable the firewall, thinking it might be a network problem, but it keeps giving me the same error.

I have read several other answers, but none has succeeded in giving me a solution.

Any help is more than appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: check permission of user who running app on server

Comment: I have checked the permissions and the user has access to the application folder and the certificate folder